# Vertical centering a text for multi row in an uneven table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'd would like to center a text within a `\multirow` cell ("Predicted condition", see image),in the working code given. But when I increase the size of the other cells ("True positive" and so on, see image), by `\parbox`, and do a line break for the `multirow` cell, the vertical centering for the text ("Predicted condition") doesn't work. Can someone give me a hint what the mistake is, I don't see it.

```
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}    
    \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{True condition} \\ 
\cline{2-4}
& \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Total population} & Condition positive & Condition negative \\
 \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Predicted condition}} &\multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\parbox{3cm}{Predicted condition\\
    positive}} & \parbox[c][2cm]{3cm}{True\\ positive} & \parbox[c][2cm]{3cm}{False\\ positive}\\ 
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\parbox{3cm}{Predicted condition\\
    negative}} & \parbox[c][2cm]{3cm}{False\\ negative} & \parbox[c][2cm]{3cm}{False\\ positive}\\ 
\cline{1-4}
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

[image: exmaple table]

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I wonder, if you really want a row 2cm high, ot only some vertical padding above and below the rows?

Comment: I was playing around with the parameters, it was the last setting. Sure the padding would be better

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler code, using the `makecell` package. The key point is the number of lines in `\multirow` doesn't denote the number of `rows`, but the number of `lines` (or an equivalent).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-0.9cm]{0pt}{2cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
    \cline{3-4}
    & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{True condition} \\
    \cline{2-4}
      & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Total population} \\
    \cline{1-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirowcell{6}[0.5ex]{Predicted condition}}
      & \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\mystrut\makecell[l]{Predicted condition \\ positive}} & \makecell[l]{True\\ positive} & \makecell[l]{False\\ positive}\\
    \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c}{}& \multicolumn{1}{ |c| }{\mystrut\makecell[l]{Predicted condition\\
    negative}} & \makecell[l]{False\\ negative} & \makecell[l]{False\\ positive}\\
    \cline{1-4}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for introduction sentence! Many people aren't aware to this :-)